# Monitoring the objects using leaflet and geoJson

Tags: javascript, geojson, leaflet

**The task is:**

*Show objects (markers) on map from existing geo data ( a set of lat/long values). The geo data updates at regular intervals, so it's like a kind of interactive monitoring of objects on the map.*

I'm using leaflet framework to reach the goal. Also I'm using geoJson to output the geoData (objects with lat/long coordinates). Here is my piece of code:

```
// for a start make it as a template
var geoData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": []
};

// add a feature, assign an id and properties
function addFeature(id, latitude, longitude, properties) {
  // first of all check if the feature have already exists
  var index = IndexOfItem(id);
  if (index >= 0) {
    // if exists then update only coordinates and properties
    geoData.features[index].geometry.coordinates = [longitude, latitude];
    geoData.features[index].properties.popupContent = properties;
  } else {
    // add new feature
    var feature = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [longitude, latitude]
      },
      "properties": {
        "popupContent": properties
      },

      "id": id
    };
    geoData.features.push(feature);
  }
}

// search and return the index of feature if exists
function IndexOfItem(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < geoData.features.length; i++) {
    if (id == geoData.features[i].id) {
      return i;
    }
  };
  return -1;
}
```

The piece of code works fine. After that, I add a new layer of these features, and when the array is updated (a few features change the coordinates), I have to remove the layer from the map and create a new L.geoJson(geoData) object. The process repeats over and over, while feature's coordinates updates.

Actually I'm not good at JavaScript and there is only that way I can solve the task. But it seems to me that it's like a hard coding, probably there is some JavaScript methods to solve the problem more elegantly. Can somebody give me piece of advice (or an idea) how to do this better or even obtain more performance? 
I will be very appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

You should just use L.layerGroup and add and remove from that collection to manage. Perhaps also use a data-binding framework to cache the map view so that it will change live instead of having to possibly refresh.